# Tomcat still running, but Java deleted

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have Tomcat running on a server with OpenJDK 7 (on an antiquated Ubuntu version, 12.04). I did an install of OpenJDK 8 on this machine, hoping to be able to switch between the Java versions, but when I went to do 'update-alternatives', only OpenJDK 8 was there - it seems to have deleted OpenJDK 7, which is potentially disastrous (the applications running on Tomcat won't run under Java 8).

The thing which I find mystifying is that Tomcat is still running OK, even though the directory for the Java it uses has been deleted. I don't know how that is even possible. If I do `ps aux | grep tomcat`, I see this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx640m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Yet the directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` no longer exists. How can this be? I will need to reinstall Open JDK 7, because Tomcat will presumably not survive a restart. Unfortunately that is not proving trivial because I now get this message when I try to install:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.12.04.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I presume this is a result of the installation of the PPA which was required to be able to install OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Best guess is that with everything loaded and running in memory there is no need for Tomcat to refer back to the directory where Java fired up, though if this is in production I'd be a bit nervous in case it does need maybe load something else in at some point. This doesn't answer your main question, but it's just a thought on the 'how can this be?' question

Comment: Yes, that was my supposition, too. Didn't think it was possible. But I've installed jdk-7-oracle on the machine (directory copied from another Ubuntu 12.04 server) and configured /etc/default/tomcat7 to use it, just in case it does restart. Hope it will work but can't afford to test it...

Comment: Fingers crossed - hopefully someone else out there has been in the same situation and can confirm before you.have to restart - good luck

Comment: I was able to start successfully with the new JVM in place.

Comment: Brilliant - I've been worrying for you!